# PhpStorm does not recognize remote debugger from docker(-compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpstorm

My dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN pecl install -o -f redis
RUN pecl install -o -f xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable redis
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install locales-all -y
```

My docker-compose file

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  redis:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis_mp
    volumes:
    - redis-data:/data
    # if we need a custom redis configuration
#    - ./docker//usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

  mysql:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mysql:5.6
    container_name: mysql_mp
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      # So you can use a database client on your host machine
    - 3306:3306
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    volumes:
    - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    # if we need a custom mysql configuration
#    - ./docker/etc/mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d

  apache:
    restart: unless-stopped
#    image: php:7.2-apache
    build: ./docker/Dockerfiles/apache
    container_name: apache_mp
#    command: bash -c "docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql && service apache2 restart"
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    - redis
    - certbot

    ports:
      # Exposing both http and https
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
    environment:
      - APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public/
    volumes:
    - .:/home/medpets/WWW/
    - ./docker/etc/apache2:/etc/apache2/
    - ./docker/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    - apache-log:/home/medpets/LOG/
    - ./docker/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt/
    - ./docker/etc/ssl:/etc/ssl/

  certbot:
    restart: "no"
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot_mp
    volumes:
    - ./docker/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt/

volumes:
  mysql-data:
  redis-data:
  apache-log:
```

The problem

[image]

Comment: If you click "Refresh" button next to "PHP executable" field (on the right). What it will do? Will it show any error message?

Comment: @LazyOne `Failed to parse validation script output`

Comment: Try this solution: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000335990/comments/360000052099